# Changing style through JavaScript doesn't work with variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to do is change the left margin of a DOM element based on a variable in JavaScript. This function **works**:

```
function updateTabs(i) {
    console.log('Switching to tab ' + i)
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            document.querySelector('#About-content1').style.marginLeft = "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            document.querySelector('#About-content1').style.marginLeft = "-100%";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.querySelector('#About-content1').style.marginLeft = "-199%";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This successfully sets the margin-left property like I want it to. However, I don't want to call `document.querySelector` every time I call the `updateTabs` function. I tried this:

```
var contentDiv1 = document.querySelector('#About-content1');

function updateTabs(i) {
    console.log('Switching to tab ' + i)
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
            break;
        case 2:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "-199%";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

However, this only works the first time I call the function. After that, it prints "Switching to tab" but doesn't actually modify the style. Is there any way I could change the style without having to call `document.querySelector` every time?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that I had a Vue.js element connected to the same element, so the element was changed. I moved the Vue.js declaration to before the `const contentDiv1 = document.querySelector('#About-content1')`, and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that the second time around it doesn't know what `contentDiv1` is how about you put that inside the function like this:

```
function updateTabs(i) {
var contentDiv1 = document.querySelector('#About-content1');
    console.log('Switching to tab ' + i)
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "0";
            break;
        case 1:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "-100%";
            break;
        case 2:
            contentDiv1.style.marginLeft = "-199%";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So now everytime the function runs it knows what `contentDiv1` is. So now you  still call document.querySelector only once but the function know what you want.

Comment: But that was the question to begin with

Comment: what do you mean? its still just one document.querySelector as the OP desired and you can have infinite cases in there with ```contentDiv1``` only. Plus you are adding px instead of % which are very different behaviours.

Comment: It was for demonstration only. His code seems to execute. He says the difference between working code and not working ode is the caching of the div object which is not the case. We are not discussing how the code executes but IF the code executes. Anyway, I am not wasting anymore time when OP cannot show proper HTML

Comment: _Is there any way I could change the style without having to call document.querySelector every time?_ was the original question

Answer (score 0):

The question is missing some context, but if Hadi Pawar's answer isn't correct, my guess is that the element is being destroyed and recreated. This should validate that:

```
var contentDiv1 = document.querySelector('#About-content1');

contentDiv1.myResize = function(i) {
    console.log('Switching to tab ' + i)
    var offsets = [0, -100, -199];
    if( i > offsets.length ) return;
    this.style.marginLeft = offsets[i] + '%';
}

[...]

contentDiv1.myResize( n );
```

Now, when you call resize, you will get a hard error if 'contentDiv1' loses scope. Otherwise, the logic is contained within the element itself.